# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_vaules'

Tags: python

I'm learning the machine, I wrote the above code while trying to delete missing values

> TypeError: __init __ () got an unexpected keyword argument I got a
>   'missing_vaules' error, where is the error, how can I fix it ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
#kodlar
#veri yükleme 

veriler=pd.read_csv("eksikveriler.csv")

print(veriler)
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer



imputer= Imputer(missing_vaules='NaN',strategy='mean',axix=0)
Yas=veriler.iloc[:,1:4].values

imputer=Imputer.fit(Yas[:,1:4])
Yas[:,1:4]=Imputer.transform(Yas[:,1:4])
print(Yas)
```

Comment: what about reading the error message instead of wasting everyone's time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imputer= Imputer(missing_vaules='NaN',strategy='mean',axix=0) Yas=veriler.iloc[:,1:4].values
```

should be

```
imputer= Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='mean',axix=0) Yas=veriler.iloc[:,1:4].values
```

with the misspelling of `values` repaired.